# Maximize the sum of absolute difference between max and min elements of all non overlapping sub-arrays that can be formed from an array?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, greedy

for example :
A = [2, 3, 0, 1, 5]

Now A can be divided into multiple sub-arrays
One way to do so is : A ~ [2], [3, 0], [1, 5]

Now the sum of absolute difference between max and min elements of all non overlapping sub-arrays that can be formed from an array is:

```
=> max([2]) - min([2]) + max([3, 0]) - min([3, 0]) + max([5, 1]) - min([5, 1]) 
=> 2 - 2 + 3 - 0 + 5 - 1
=> 7
```

Constraints for the Problem:

```
1 <= length of array <= 10^6

-10^9 <= A[i] <= 10^9
```

Comment: In your example, the subarrays have a length of 1 or 2. Is it a constraint or just an example?

Comment: @Damien I think the question is how to best divide the array.

Comment: I think the same, but wanted to be sure. Note that even with "1-2" constraint, you still have a great amount of possibilities. @גלעדברקן

Comment: @Damien there is no constraint on the length of the sub-array,                                          
1 <= length-of-sub-array <= length of array.

Comment: @גלעדברקן  u are right, in a way we have to find the optimal way to divide the array to maximize our ans.

Comment: Are all the elements distinct?

Comment: @AKSingh duplicates could be present in the array.

Comment: I did post one Greedy Solution to your problem. However, it is not meant for duplicates. In case of duplicates, solution need to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can have an `O(n)` dynamic program. Let's save three states per element:

```
1. best_sum_if_highest

2. best_sum_if_lowest

3. best_sum_if_neither
```

At each iteration, an element can (1) extend an earlier, lower or equal element's range if it was the highest of a section, (2) extend an earlier higher or equal element's range if it was the lowest of a section, or (3) not contribute to the overall sum.

Note that (1) and (2) are mutually exclusive since if the last different earlier element is higher, then the element cannot fulfill (1) and vice versa.

Let's assume that we merge sequences of more than two contiguous identical elements to a maximum of two because the extras cannot contribute.

Dynamic program:

```
// Extend lower highest
dp[i][0] = A[i] - A[i-1] + max(dp[i-1][0], dp[i-1][2])
  if A[i-1] ≤ A[i]
  
// Extend higher lowest
dp[i][1] = A[i-1] - A[i] + max(dp[i-1][1], dp[i-1][2])
  if A[i-1] ≥ A[i]
  
// Don't contribute
dp[i][2] = max(
  dp[i-1][0],
  dp[i-1][1],
  dp[i-1][2]
)
```

Example 1:

```
[2, 3, 0, 1, 5]

A[i]  states 
2     [0, 0, 0]
3     [1, 0, 0]
0     [0, 3, 1]
1     [2, 0, 3]
5     [7, 0, 3]
```

Example 2:

```
[1, 5, 2, 1, 6, 0, 7]

A[i]  states 
1     [0,  0,  0]
5     [4,  0,  0]
2     [0,  3,  4]
1     [0,  5,  4]
6     [9,  0,  5]
0     [0, 14,  9]
7     [16, 0, 14]
```

JavaScript code with random comparison against brute force (well, naive `O(n^2)` at any rate):

```js
function f(A){
  const dp = new Array(A.length);
  
  for (let i=0; i<A.length; i++)
    dp[i] = [0, 0, 0];
  
  for (let i=1; i<A.length; i++){
    if (A[i] >= A[i-1]){
      dp[i][0] = A[i] - A[i-1] + Math.max(dp[i-1][0], dp[i-1][2]);
      dp[i][1] = 0;
    }
    
    if (A[i] <= A[i-1]){
      dp[i][0] = 0;
      dp[i][1] = A[i-1] - A[i] + Math.max(dp[i-1][1], dp[i-1][2]);
    }
    
    dp[i][2] = Math.max(...dp[i-1]);
  }
  
  return Math.max(...dp[A.length - 1]);
}


function bruteForce(A){
  const dp = new Array(A.length);
  
  dp[0] = 0;
  dp[-1] = 0;
  
  for (let i=1; i<A.length; i++){
    let min = A[i];
    let max = A[i];
    let best = dp[i-1];
    
    for (let j=i-1; j>=0; j--){
      min = Math.min(min, A[j]);
      max = Math.max(max, A[j]);
      best = Math.max(best, max - min + dp[j-1]);
    }
    
    dp[i] = best;
  }
  
  return dp[A.length - 1];
}

var numTests = 1000;

for (let i=0; i<numTests; i++){
  const N = 10;
  const A = [];
  const n = 50;
  for (let j=0; j<n; j++){
    const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1 << N));
    A.push(num);
  }

  const fA = f(A);
  const brute = bruteForce(A);

  if (fA != brute){
    console.log('Mismatch:');
    console.log(A);
    console.log(fA, brute);
    console.log('');
  }
}

console.log("Done testing.");
```